# Wamp not running with mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, wamp

I used this tutorial:

http://martinprzybyla.com/2011/02/01/how-to-get-python-working-with-apache-and-wampserver-win-7/

And many similar ones to try and get the mod_wsgi module to work on wamp. After doing all the steps wamp will not start up and I don't get any messages in the log files. I even changed the LogLevel from warn to info but nothing is logged.

I have tried:

1. Reintalling python to make sure it is installed for everyone
2. Rebooting
3. Grabbing different mod_wsgi binaries
4. Adding the configurations one by one to see at which point wamp fails to start; which is the first line: LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjkeO.jpg

Comment: If this is for development environment, don't bother. It's better and faster to use development servers (your favourite framework will most likely have a runner for one, and if not — use wsgiref) than Apache.

Comment: Is your Apache also loading mod_python by chance? Also look at bit more closely in the Apache error logs because any failure to load the module would generally log some sort of error, it just may look obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 64 bit version of WAMP?

If so you need to make sure you are using the 64 bit version of mod_wsgi.

You can find it here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/